# How can I pass information from a python process into a calling process

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a data analysis tool that I wrote in Python. I want to be able to schedule this tool to be run as new data comes in, which I can do in Visual Basic.Net.  What I want to do is have a VB process spawn the python process and then send the data it receives from the python off to be reported, but I haven't been able to find much online for this kind of scenario.  What tools should I be using here to make this happen?

**Edit:**
What I ended up doing was using .Nets's System.Diagnostic.Process class to start the Python process, and then simply read off of the standard output stream.  [This site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/078fac06-853b-4e2b-9659-8a8f5cb2d26c/readwrite-data-to-stdinout-using-vb?forum=vbgeneral) explained how to do this on the VB side.

Comment: Why don't you use the `subprocess` module?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It is already tagged with subprocess and he spawns a python from VB. can you return more information that a returncode to the process that spawned the python processing by it (never used it so far)? Or do you mean spawning the VB from python when done processing?

Comment: I meant use the Python `subprocess` module to do the spawning, which provides IPC out of the box.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the subprocess module does the opposite of what I want.  I don't need to spawn another process from the Python code.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for a file based approch:

- vb tells python about the file to create as well as the data and waits till processing is done, reads the file in again
- You could use a shared database

Or interprocess communication:

- you could use "the ususal" interprocess communication stuff: named pipes ([Python read named PIPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089776/python-read-named-pipe)), client/server ([UDP Client/Server Socket in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893804/udp-client-server-socket-in-python)) , sockets ([(Very) basic Python client socket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749341/very-basic-python-client-socket-example)), ...

A good starting point would be the python documentation on [interprocess communication](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html)

Comment: @scottmermelstein thx for the edit :) was not quite finished adding other SO-Threads in