# How to explicitly set the client source port in UDP communication in C?

Tags: sockets, server, udp, client

I have two C files i.e server.c and client.c. Initially in server side I created the socket and fixed a port on which the server can listen and send . But in client side when I send any message to the server side how should I explicitly assign a client source port on which it can listen. Everytime the kernel assigns a random port no. between 1024 to 65535. But how can I explicitly define the client source port in UDP communication?

[This link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicitly-assigning-port-number-client-socket/) I found for TCP communication. I want for UDP.

For example:
On server side:
Server Created
Binded Correctly
Listening ...
Connection Established
connection established with IP : 10.0.2.15 and PORT : 40064
Client : Hello

On Client side:
Client Created
Binded Correctly
Client Connected
Server : Hello

40064 is randomly assigned by the kernel to the client. But I want to explicitly set that port on client side for UDP. Is there any function or command to do it?

Comment: See the first answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/27893987/6156470

Comment: In this case the solution is the same for UDP as it is for TCP. Make a call to the `bind()` function to associate your client's UDP socket with a specific port before you start sending datagrams through that socket.  If you don't need to bind the client socket to a specific address then you should set an all-zero address in the `struct sockaddr_in` argument to the `bind()` call.  (Your TCP example sets a specific address, but that's not required and it's often not desirable.)

Comment: Yeah got it . Thank you @ottomeister.