Trying to receive Data from an IP Scale through a Network
I am trying to write an app which will receive an IP Scale "print" data (what would go on a receipt), through a network connection.
I would like to achieve this sing only the app as the "receiver" of data and without a Client-Server set of Apps.
The IP Scale is configured with its own IP address and Port.
Every Tutorial or Forum I have come across points to a Client Side app AND a Server side app.
I am using only 1x pc to connect to the IP scale.
The closest I could get to a connection was using the following example:
import socket

TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0" #my own IP used instead of this one
TCP_PORT = 1025 #the port set up on the IP Scale
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print("connected: ", s)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
print("received data: ", data)

This outputs:
connected:  <socket.socket fd=188, family=2, type=2, proto=0, laddr=('pc IP Address', 53797), raddr=('IP Scale IP Address', 22)>

Nothing prints except when I change the buffer to 0, then I get the following:

received data:  b''

Please [edit] your question to include a link to the product on the manufacturer's website so we can get a better idea of what needs to be done.

I am not sure the manufacturer is relevant. I used Wireshark to check UDP traffic, and can see that the data is coming through to my pc. However, all forms of python script I can find do not appear to even "print" data, nor can I tell if the app is actually doing anything with the specified port data.

My query is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893804/udp-client-server-socket-in-python

Does the "Receiving" code at UDP Communication show anything? Have you tried a different port number in case something else is grabbing the data before your code gets it? (Maybe the manufacturer has an entry in this Wikipedia list of registered ports that could be expected to be usable.)

Wireshark show all UDP comms coming through on the preconfigured port 1003. I now also tried disabling my Firewall and AVG but this did not change anything. Data is visible on Wireshark but not on my Python app. I have also tried different port numbers to no avail.

I now get the following in the Console:
"Starting up on  port 9000
Waiting to receive message..."
#Never gets a message
